# Why should the gradient of an $n-1$-manifold in $\mathbb R^n$ be nonzero?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

I am reading [this chapter about manifolds here](http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/chap5.pdf) and the author writes (page 2):

There is a very important restriction we impose on this situation. It is motivated by our recognition from p. 2–43 that $\nabla g(x)$ is a vector which should be orthogonal to $M$ at the point $x \in M$. If $M$ is truly $(n−1)$-dimensional, then this vector $\nabla g(x)$ should probably be nonzero.

Here $M$ is a level set of $g$.

> Why does $M$ is $n-1$-dimensional imply that the gradient of $g$
>   should be nonzero?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $M$ is not entirely $(n-1)$-dimensional. That is, suppose there's at least one  point $x_0\in M$ such that there's an open $n$-ball $U\subset M$ containing $x_0$. Then the single *"restriction"* imposed by $g$ in the definition of $M$:
$$M=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: g(x)=c\}$$
has failed to actually remove one *"degree of freedom"* at $x_0$. In other words, there can only be an $n$-ball in $M$ surrounding $x_0$ if going in any direction whatsoever doesn't change the value of $g$, i.e., every partial derivative of $g$ is $0$, i.e. $\nabla g(x_0)=0$.

Thus, if we want to ensure there are no such points $x_0$ for any choice of $c$, then we should require that $\nabla g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. (And it is not hard to reverse the argument to show this is sufficient as well.)

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer! Ok, so at points of dimension $n$ we cannot have nonzero gradient. But what about points of dimension $n-k$ for $k \ge 2$?

Comment: Basically, it is impossible to have dimension $<n-1$ because there's only one "restriction", so at most "one degree of freedom" will ever be removed (unless the value of $c$ that's chosen is a critical point of $g$, then all bets are off). See [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set#Level_sets_versus_the_gradient) for example.